# Update will only update if an added space is used, creating errors

Tags: php, sql, regex

I  am doing an update query, but it will only update if a space is used after the inserted variable, which is then adding a space to the database. I have used trim and rtrim to try and get rid of the space to no avail. I just want to see if anyone has run into this type of issue

I have never had this problem occur and have deleted this and retried multiple versions of the Update. Nothing works unless I put in a space.

Below is a space after '$video_id before the closing ' which you can't see here.

```
$sqlTest = "UPDATE Media SET videolink = '$video_id ' WHERE id_assoc = '$idperformer'";
```

What works:

```
$sqlTest = "UPDATE Media SET videolink = '$video_id ' WHERE id_assoc = '$idperformer'";
```

What I need to work:

```
$sqlTest = "UPDATE Media SET videolink = '$video_id' WHERE id_assoc = '$idperformer'"
```

Here's a sample of the `$videolink` input data:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="youtube.com/embed/Yj07347rEqo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

And I extract the `$video_id` from it using the following code:

```
$string = $videolink; 
preg_match('/(?<=\/embed\/)[^"\']*/', $string, $matches); 
$video_id = $matches[0];
```

And the preg_match above does grab the needed data in this case: `Yj07347`, but I assume that is then adding in the space or `\`.

Comment: well like you said this is weird... what is the videolink field type in mysql ? And what type is $video_id in PHP ?

Comment: The field is videolink varchar(255) latin1_swedish_ci, the type is  embed code from youtube so the actual data is just a string.

Comment: What is the value in the database column, does it have a space at the end??

Comment: If the string ends with \ and you are not escaping it, that could maybe be an issue.

Comment: Also, you should use prepared statements, like ADyson says.

Comment: I changed it over to the prepared statement, but it now adds a \ instead of a space. So I believe there is an escape issue like Urlik McArdle states. I am using:$string = $videolink;
preg_match('/(?<=\/embed\/)[^"\']*/', $string,$matches); to remove everything except the embed links...Is there something in that could be adding the \ or space?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said precisely what goes wrong, or how, so this may not be the complete solution, but have you tried using parameterised queries?

It stands a good chance of fixing a range of seemingly syntax-related issues such as this, but also it should be used as standard anyway, to protect against SQL Injection attacks. Concatenating variables directly into your queries the way you are doing can be the source of several problems.

Here's a simple example of a parameterised version of your query, using `mysqli`:

```
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE Media SET videolink = ? WHERE id_assoc = ?");
$stmt->bind_param('ss',$video_id, $idperformer);
$stmt->execute();
```

The mysqli code will then take care of escaping the data correctly, and you don't have to worry about placement of quote marks etc.

Here's a similar example using `PDO`, in case you are using that instead of `mysqli`:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare('UPDATE Media SET videolink = :vidlink WHERE id_assoc = :idperformer');
$stmt->bindParam(':vidlink', $video_id);
$stmt->bindParam(':idperformer', $idperformer);
$stmt->execute();
```

N.B. If you are using some other database library (e.g. for SQL Server, Oracle or PostreSQL) then you can research the correct way to create parameterised queries using that library - they all support them.

Comment: So this now adds a \ instead of a space. I am using this code to remove everything except the embedded Id:$string = $videolink;
preg_match('/(?<=\/embed\/)[^"\']*/', $string,$matches);
$video_id = $matches[0];

Comment: Hm, it sounds like maybe the data is already pre-escaped or something. Or perhaps there is really a hidden character. Where does the variable data come from? Is it from user input? Do you do any other processing on it before you put it into the query? I think maybe we are missing some information. Can you give us an example of the raw string you are receiving, before you process it?

Comment: The variable data is: <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Yj07347rEqo" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe> . And the preg_match above does grab the needed data in this case: Yj07347, but I assume that is then adding in the space or \.

Comment: Just to verify, I made an executable version of that snippet: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/5da008f5f8c2b781ff85a755d91464f8e1eb2f66 - note I added some delimiters round it just to see if there were invisible spaces. It does not appear to add a space or a backslash. Are you certain this is the correct input data? Does anything else happen to the data between this code, and when it gets added to the SQL query? As it stands, I cannot reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thank you ADyson, after looking at that snippet and  running a bunch of different tests...it hit me square in the face. I have been running the link through mysqli_real_escape_string. I just deleted that and now it works.

Comment: Well spotted. If you use parameterised queries, then mysqli_real_escape_string is redundant. Glad you fixed it.